# React Native and font variants

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I've created an React Native app, targeted mainly at iOS.
I'm using custom fonts, and can see they are successfully integrated into the app via some debug in AppDelegate.m (in XCode):

```
for (NSString* family in [UIFont familyNames])
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", family);
    for (NSString* name in [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName: family])
    {
      NSLog(@" %@", name);
    }
  }
```

resulting in:-

MyFontFamily

MyFontFamilyFontOne

MyFontFamilyFontTwo

My issue is accessing the specific fonts in a < Text > element - I always see the same font rendered when using the family or the exact font name, e.g.

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'MyFontFamily'}}>hello</Text>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'MyFontFamilyFontOne'}}>hello</Text>
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'MyFontFamilyFontTwo'}}>hello</Text>
```

results in the same font rendered.

Outputting the same in HTML results in the desired outcome, e.g. fonts One and Two are different.

Comment: If you use for example `AmericanTypewriter-Light` instead of your custom fonts does it run?

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Yanush verified you have properly linked your fonts. After with custom font you must set the **fontFamily**, the **fontWeight** and the **fontStyle**

Comment: One and two are essentially separate fonts although they are the same family. When viewing them in MacOS font book, they are listed as "One" and "Two" under "MyFontFamily".

Comment: I know!!! But there is no problem! When you use each in the style property you must set the fontWeight and fontStyle otherwise react Native will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have linked the fonts correctly.
The correct way of linking fonts in react native is as described:

1. Create a fonts dir under your project dir, eg: ./assets/fonts
2. Edit package.json file and add these lines:
   "rnpm": {
   "assets": [
     "./app/assets/fonts"
   ]
   }
3. Link the fonts: in your project dir run "react-native link"